# LightGBM Installation Issues - Python

Tags: python, git, lightgbm

I am following the Installation guide found at https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/wiki/Installation-Guide to install LightGBM. In the MinGW shell, I am able to download the git repo, and then cd into the build directory. When I try try the following command:

```
 cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-
3.9/Modules/CMakeMinGWFindMake.cmake:12 (message):
sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:

 C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe

 For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

 Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.

 If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles.

 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:8 (PROJECT)


 CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to 
 "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to 
 select a different build tool.
 CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to " 
 MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to 
 select a different build tool.
 CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
 CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I also tryed removing the sh.exe from my path.

Can anyone point me to a possible solution? I am guessing I installed cmake incorrect?

Comment: My guess is it can't find gnu `make`. Do you have a full MinGW or just the one that comes with Git?

Comment: Think I have the one that comes with Git...found here: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: In their [installation guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/wiki/Installation-Guide) they ask for MinGW64, try installing it and using that enviroment to compile

Comment: @yorodm , I believe that I am using MinGW64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution presented itself:

```
pip install lightgbm
```

problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..` two times .

Answer (score 0):

*create a new environment in conda according to requirements shown in lightgbm and than create a environment list in jupyter and use according to your package by changing in kernel setting it will work fine.*

**how to create new env??**
conda create --n py37_64 python=3.7
also download according 32 bit or 64 bit for lightgbm 64 bit is used for that:
config --env --set subdir win--64

and activate particular env here it is py37_64
so command will be:
activate py37_64

and install lightgbm 
pip install lightgbm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxA8N.png)now see the magic and use this env in your jupyter notebook how??

conda install nb_conda

for using this kernels in notebook you have to deactivate env and activate it again

now see your notebook

here you can see in image im actually using this now you can switch kernels according to 
your requirement